# find values in php array in sequence

Tags: php, arrays, sequence

I am working with an array constructed from input from a form. I need to find if two values are in the array in sequence. If I use in_array it comes back true searching for one value or the other, but I need to find if they are in sequence as there is a chance two values are in the array. Example:

```
 [0] => location [1] => Riverside [2] => location [3] => Other [4] => subcat1 [5] => Motorcycle [6] => subcat2 [7] => Other.
```

If I use array_search or in_array, looking for 'Other' it returns true and stops on the first value found, but I need to know if the value subcat2 is immediately followed by 'Other' in the array. Using the values repopulates the form and since 'Other' is in the array twice (or more), it marks all the 'Other' options in the form. I want to capture the value pairs. Any ideas?

Comment: `Any ideas?`  Yes I have many, what have you tried.  I imagine you need to loop though the array, keep track of the last value (value from previous iteration of the loop) and if that matches the current value then do whatever it is you do with them when you find them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function.

```
function findpair($initial_array,$value1,$value2){
 $found=false;
 foreach($initial_array as $key=>$value){
  if(isset($initial_array[$key+1])){
   if($value1==$value and $initial_array[$key+1]==$value2){$found=true;}
  }
 }
 return $found;
}
findpair($array,'Other','subcat2');
```

You can change $found to return the key of the first found value/pair if you want. This just returns TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work exactly but it did put me on the right track and I think I have the answer. BIG help!

Comment: Up vote but not showing as I am too much of a newbie!

Comment: Was also missing the second parenthesis in the isset line :)

Comment: Haha, yes, sometimes I just write code and work with my error codes later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$found='false';
$value1 = 'subcat2';
$value2 = 'Other';
     foreach($local_array as $key=>$value){
           if($value1==$value && $local_array[$key+1]==$value2){$found='Yes';}
     }
echo $found;
```

This solution works and serves the purpose